# Polars python poincare plot

Tags: python, plot, python-polars

I am trying to arrange my data in polars for a poincare plot.  The poincare plot is a type of scatter plot where the x-coordinate of any given point is the measured value n and the y-coordinate is the measured value after a chosen delay (e.g. 5 mins).

For example, for the following data:

| measured | delta |
| --- | --- |
| 120 | 0 |
| 104 | 5 |
| 103 | 15 |

if the delay factor is 5, I would want to plot the point (120,104).  I would want to skip plotting (104,103), b/c the time delta there is 10, etc...

Any advice on how to do this?  thanks!

I was thinking maybe I could filter for all data where delta + 5 exists, but not sure how to do that across rows.

```py
df.filter( pl.col('delta') == pl.col('delta') + 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to find coordinates like this:

`[(x_t, x_{t+1}), (x_{t+1}, x_{t+2}), ...]`

but before that, you need to filter data by condition `diff(delta) <= 5`

So, for example, you can do smth like that:

```py
df.filter(
    # 1. find difference & filter
    pl.col("delta").diff().fill_null(0) <= 5
).with_columns(
    # 2. find coordinates                      shift values by 1 position up
    coord = pl.concat_list( #                    /
        [pl.col("measured"), pl.col("measured").shift_and_fill(
            -1, pl.col("measured").last())]
    )
)
```

```
┌──────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ measured ┆ delta ┆ coord      │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ list[i64]  │
╞══════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 120      ┆ 0     ┆ [120, 104] │
│ 104      ┆ 5     ┆ [104, 104] │
└──────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

#### Plotting

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(
    x=df.select(pl.col("coord").arr.get(0)),
    y=df.select(pl.col("coord").arr.get(1))
);
```

Comment: hmmm, i think something like that might work if the delay is 5 and expecting delta between rows to be 5, it will probably fail on a larger delay where the number of rows constituting that delay is variable.

Comment: I'm thinking this is too tricky to do in polars and just implemented a solution in python...i'm sure its way slower, but working well.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

```
# initial dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'measured' : [120, 104, 103],
    'delta' : [0, 5, 15]
})

# you can set any delay
delay = 5

# filter rows matching the delay
df \
    .with_columns( delta_2 = pl.col('delta') +delay) \
    .join(df, left_on='delta_2', right_on='delta')

# result
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────────┬───────┬─────────┬────────────────┐
│ measured ┆ delta ┆ delta_2 ┆ measured_right │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---            │
│ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64     ┆ i64            │
╞══════════╪═══════╪═════════╪════════════════╡
│ 120      ┆ 0     ┆ 5       ┆ 104            │
└──────────┴───────┴─────────┴────────────────┘

The value in the column 'measured' will go on the x-axis, and the value in column 'measured_right' will go on the y-axis.
```

You can then use matplotlib as proposed by glebcom.

I would also check out about running this as a lazyframe (i.e. adding df.lazy() and collect() at the end) for better performance

Comment: i think  you are right about using a join, but I don't get delta2 or measured_right running the above code

Comment: Hi @1FatKhazar, you mean you don't get what delta2 or measured_right mean?
measured_right is the measure going on the y-axis, and delta2 is its delta.

happy to help you further